# Visual Studio 2010 untracked files

Tags: vb.net, version-control, source-control-explorer

Is there a way to find untracked files that are inside your solution in source control?  I Couldn't find an answer.

Already tried doing a `git status` or `svn status` to see if it was using any of those. (You can probably tell by now that I'm a VB.NET noob.)

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to tell by the lack on a Source Control icon next to the file, or in most cases, it is a PLUS showing that it is new and will be added next time you checkin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a Visual Studio command prompt use the [tf folderdiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385992%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) command.

something like

`tf folderdiff c:\myLocalFolder $/TeamProject/MyServerFolder /recursive`

You can also filter out certain types of file so if you don't want to include build output you can use something like this

`tf folderdiff c:\myLocalFolder $/TeamProject/MyServerFolder /recursive /filter:!*.exe,!*.pdb`